# find the integer number of items from a list given a probability

Tags: python, python-3.5, probability

Assume, I have a list with a length of 20 and every day, I want to find out the integer number of items from this list given a certain probability. After extracting the integer number of items, I want to do further operations.

```
m = [10,20,30,40, 50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200]
prob = 0.2
```

In the above example, I want to find out that how many items will be selected on average everyday given a 0.2 probability. So on average, from a list of length 20 and probability 0.2, I should get number of items = 4 every day. How can I get number of events given a probability in Python? Should I use Poisson to get number of events in a time period but I am not sure, how to include the size of the list in a Poisson function in Python. And how to get integer number of items when probability is lets say 0.113 or 0.31 etc. How can I obtain this in Python?

Comment: `prob * len(m)`? You seem to be over-complicating it.

Comment: Is there a relation between the probability and the number of items chosen?? I don't believe there is any?

Comment: Should it even be int(prob * len(m)), as John Coleman says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the selection or not of each list element is an independent event with probability `prob`, the number of items selected is a binomial random variable with parameters `len(m)` and `prob`. The expected value of such a random variable is `prob * len(m)`.

If you want to *simulate* this random variable (rather than compute its expected value) you can use:

```
import random

def binomial_variate(n,p):
    return sum(random.random() < p for _ in range(n))
```

For example,

```
>>> trials = [binomial_variate(20,0.12) for _ in range(100)]
>>> trials
[5, 6, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
>>> sum(trials)/100
2.55
>>> 20*0.12
2.4
```

Comment: Prob * len(m) works fine when you get the integer number from this multiplication but when you get a decimal number, then you need to round off using int(len(m) * prob). Assuming a fixed length of list of 20 and prob = 0.113, you get 2.26, and with int(), you get 2. It will cause lot of difference in the total count after drawing number of elements 1000 times (2*1000 vs 2.26*1000). Is there any other way to get an int number of items straight from the probability calculation without using int(), similar to Poisson distribution where it returns integer number of events in a time period)?

Comment: @HT121 The expected number *is* `prob * len(m)`. I don't see why you want to round a mathematically meaningful answer to something which doesn't make as much sense. If it isn't the expected number that you are trying to calculate, just what are you trying to do? Note that when you run the experiment, the actual number selected will be an integer but will vary from trial to trial. When you average many such trials, the result need not be an integer.

Comment: Actually I need to find out how many agents will move to a new location every 24 hours. So these number of agent can only be integers. I could select random agents given a probability and move it but the problem is, I need to first see if the new location has a free spot to accommodate the new agent. Therefore, I wanted to first extract the number of agents to be moved within the next 24 hours and then every time step which is very small, I keep on looking if a space a available in the next location. when available, I randomly select an agent and move and subtract 1 from the count variable.

Comment: but thanks anyway, your answer is perfectly correct for a general case.

Comment: @HT121 I added information about how to simulate the random variable (Python's random module lacks a direct way to generate such random variables, so you have to write your own function (or use a different module)).

Comment: Your last edits are quite closer to what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like `int(len(m) * prob)` in your python code and it will do the trick. Be sure to surround with a try/catch to avoid errors.
You should also verify that the `prob` value is composed between 0 and 1 included